# Prove that $a^2(1+b^4)+b^2(1+a^4)≤(1+a^4)(1+b^4)$

Tags: inequality

Prove that
$$a^2(1+b^4)+b^2(1+a^4)≤(1+a^4)(1+b^4).$$

This is a problem from the pre College mathematics.
Please help. This inequality has to be proved for all reals $a$ and $b$

Comment: divide it by the RHS

Comment: You can divide by $(1+a^4)(1+b^4)$ and then sufficient to show $x^2/(1+x^4)$ maximized at $1/2$

Comment: $a^2\le\frac12\left(1+a^4\right)$ and $b^2\le\frac12\left(1+b^4\right)$ because $\frac12\left(1-2x^2+x^4\right)=\frac12\left(1-x^2\right)^2\ge0$.

Comment: I'm sorry to those who marked the question duplicate . I didn't knew that it has already been asked. Also thanks to those who replied. It was so easy , i just didn't notice that we could divide .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your inequality in the form
$$\frac{2a^2}{1+a^4}+\frac{2b^2}{1+b^4}\le 2$$

This is true since $$\frac{2x^2}{1+x^4}\le 1$$

Comment: @ Dr.Sonnhard Graubner: you just have to divide by 2.

Comment: Aha, i have used that $$2x^2\le 1+x^4$$ and this is $$(x^2-1)^2\geq 0$$